# python pandas avoiding dupulicated csv output

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv, beautifulsoup

I am using python, but I got a problem.

Ideally, I would like to have no duplicates, but if I make a csv file, the same words will be output.
How can I avoid duplication?
I am a beginner in programming, so please be gentle with me.
Thanks.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q57JC.png)

Here is my code.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from tqdm import tqdm
from csv import writer

all_data = []
meanings = []
words = []

while True:

    spell = input("spell: ")
    r = requests.get(
        "http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term={}".format(spell))
    r.encoding = r.apparent_encoding
    data = BeautifulSoup(r.content, features="lxml")
    explanation_list = data.find("div", attrs={"class": "meaning"})
    explanation_list = explanation_list.get_text()
    print(explanation_list)
    
    meanings.append(explanation_list)
    words.append(spell)
    all_data = ({'words': words, 'meanings': meanings})

    df = pd.DataFrame(data=all_data)
    filepath = 'C:/Users/dict1.csv'
    df.to_csv(filepath, mode='a', index=False, header=None)
```

Comment: In your `while` loop you append words to your `words` list and you then use `mode='a'` (=append) when saving your `DataFrame` to `csv` file. You might want to change either of both.

Comment: so, what should I do exactly? if I change mode='a' to mode = 'w', there is no duplicate obviously, but the thing is I wanna append all_data every time I run the code. @marcel

Answer (score 1):

When you create the data frame using,

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=all_data)
```

you can check whether there are duplicates in the data frame by using,

```
df.duplicated()
```

If there are duplicates, you can remove them by using

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['name1','name2'])
```

Comment: I think the problem is caused by the last line df.to_csv.

Comment: ```
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=all_data)
    df.duplicated()
    df.drop_duplicates(subset=['words','meanings'])
    filepath = 'C:/Users/dict1.csv'
    df.to_csv(filepath, mode='w', index=False, header=None)
```
I did the above code, but I wont change.

Comment: Try header=False or can you paste the error you are getting if you are getting any?